VS code does not give suggestions when using the cite command
So i am using Latex (with biblatex) in VS Code with the latex workshop plugin. I used to use overleaf. When i put a new literature in my .bib file in overleaf and then writing \cite{} in the .tex file i would get suggested the bibid of that literature i just put in.
In VS code however i seem to only get the bibid suggested when i used them at least once in the .tex file already. Is there maybe a way to get them suggested right away? That would be very handy.
Thx!
